# CSS not doing what i want

Tags: css, sass

Im trying to make a website, i already made a navbar, the problem is that when i try to spell something in two words in the bar, it puts the second word on a new line, i know i might not need a grid layout, but i would like to keep it. So my question is, if i keep using gridlayout, how do i make the "About Me" be in one line instead of two.

I linked the pastebin which has my css code and the image (Hopefully works) should be linked aswell. It's written using SASS

https://pastebin.com/92hTJEq7

```
    :root {
    --primary-color: #007AF3;
}

body {
    background: #5C5C5C;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.navbar {
    background: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 1em 1em 1.5em 1em;


    .logo {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        position: inherit;
        z-index: 999;

        span {
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1.7em;
            left: 4em;
            z-index: 999;
        }
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        place-content: space-between;
    }

    .mobile-menu {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2em;
        right: 1em;
        border: 1px solid transparent;

        &:hover {
            opacity: 50%;
        }
    }
}

a {
    color: lime;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav.menu-btn {
    display: block;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 66%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;

    ul.primary-nav {
        margin-top: 5em;
    }

    li {
        a {
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: .5em;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            text-align: right;

            &:hover {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        }
    }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    .mobile-menu,
    .mobile-menu-exit {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar,
    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 180px auto;
        justify-content: unset;
    }

    .navbar nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        background: none;
        position: unset;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 998;

        ul {
            display: flex;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
            font-size: 1em;
            padding: .1em 1em;
        }

        ul.primary-nav {
            margin: 0;
            padding: .4em 5em 0em 5em;
        }

        li.current a {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZQ0O.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Try removing `display: block;` and add `whitespace: nowrap;` under `li a`?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is "Width" of the Navbar. You can reduce the fontsize of the text in mobile devices.

Answer (score -1):

At first, you have to provide enough space to acually display your content. After that, there‘s two options to achieve what you‘re asking for.

First is CSS:
Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.navbar-nav ul li`
If you don‘t want your layout to get mixed up, also add `overflow:hidden`. This will hide any content that doesn‘t fit your box.

The second option is to replace the space between About me with `&nbsp;`: `About&nbsp;me`. nbsp stands for no breaking space.

Comment: It kinda works, the whitespace: nowrap fixes it, but if i put overflow: hidden, it hides all but the logo, where do i specify the size of the nav to hold everything ?, i thought i did that in the grid-template-columns

Comment: yes, you have specified the width with grid-rows-column. Unfortunately, you have only provided your CSS what makes it hard to guess what’s really happening here. I guess you‘ve used the Bootstrap example. With this assumption I‘d say your total content width is used up as follows: 180px for your logo, each resume takes as much width as it needs (set to auto) + padding of twice 0.5em each. This just doesn‘t leave enough space for `About me` surrounded by 0.5em marging on each side. I usually test display errors like these by adding a different background color to each element.

Comment: hm, I don‘t really know why `overflow:hidden` hides everything. It should only hide overflowing text. But I think it‘s due to the width of your nav elements being set to auto. Personally, I‘d say your best bet is to use a logo that takes up less space on mobile devices. Cramping content is not favorable regarding accsessibility and on touch devices at some point you can simply not hit what you want anymore